# Import web source code including not displayed on page

Tags: vba, web-scraping

I want to import the web page source code in excel what I see using `View Page Source` option in Chrome. But when I import it using below code, it doesn't import all content. The values that I'm looking for do not get displayed on web page.
I'm also unable to locate the element using `getElementsByClassName` or other methods.

```
Private Sub HTML_VBA_Excel()
Dim oXMLHTTP As Object
Dim sPageHTML As String
Dim sURL As String

'Change the URL before executing the code
sURL = "http://pntaconline/getPrDetails?entry=8923060"

'Extract data from website to Excel using VBA
Set oXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
oXMLHTTP.Open "GET", sURL, False
oXMLHTTP.send
sPageHTML = oXMLHTTP.responseText

'Get webpage data into Excel
' If longer sourcecode mean, you need to save to a external text file or somewhere,
' since excel cell have some limits on storing max characters

ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1) = sPageHTML

MsgBox "XMLHTML Fetch Completed"

End Sub
```

Data I want to import is IDs and Name:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you need to understand the DOM in order to realize why this isnt loading everything.

XMLHTTP is going to load that specific resource you requested. A lot of web pages, sorry pretty much all web pages, load extra resources after the initial request is done.

If you're missing stuff, it's probably loaded on a different network request. So open up your DevTools in Chrome, make sure Network tab is recording, and watch how many network requests go in and out when you load your target page.

Essentially, this if you're using XMLHTTP, you'd have to simulate each of those to get the requests you want to scrape.

**EDIT**

So you're just kind of pasting the data response into Excel.

Better to create HTMLDocument variable then set the response from XMLHTTP to be the response like here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms762275(v=vs.85)

```
set xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.3.0");
xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://localhost/books.xml", false);
xmlhttp.send();
Debug.print(xmlhttp.responseText);
Dim xString as String
xSring = xmlhttp.responseText
'search the xString variable
```

You can then split that response for the sheet or search it and extract the values in VBA memory, rather than print to the sheet.

You could also set the xString responseText as the innerHTML for a new HTMLDocument variable

```
Dim xHTML as HTMLDocument
Set xHTML.innertext = xString
```

Comment: You're right. The content is under inactive tab I think that is the reason I'm not able to import it.

Comment: No Look its like this, you dont have to accept the answer unless it works lol. Example: Each web page is just bunch of files in a folder on someone else's PC. When you connect to the main page, the browser (chrome, firefox, ie) loads all those files. Now when you use XMLHTTP, you're saying, I want ONE file, at this SPECIFIC address. The Browser would do that for you, and put all the files together on the page you see. But since you're scraping with a direct request, you gotta find out which one is gonna get you the file with that info. Just cause it's in the dom dont mean it loads off the main

Comment: When you use DevTools, you can see a list on the Network tab in chrome or IE or FF, and it will show you each request, and each response. Here's how to use it in Chrome, and find all the detailed things, so you can take those details back to XMLHTTP, and make the request that'll find that data: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network